# Finding MIN and MAX of date column

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I am trying to find out min and max of application_date(Text data type)

```
 application_date 

   01Jan2018
   21Feb2018
   18Mar2018
   31Dec2017
   15Jan2019
```

Column is of Text data type

From the data above Min date is 31Dec2017 ,Max date is 15Jan2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select max(TO_DATE(application_date, 'DDMONYYYY')) max_date,
   min(TO_DATE(application_date, 'DDMONYYYY')) min_date
from table1
```

Answer (score 2):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/25684)**

Convert the text to DATE

```
SELECT to_date(application_date,'DDMONYYYY');
```

then

```
SELECT MAX(to_date(application_date,'DDMONYYYY')),
       MIN(to_date(application_date,'DDMONYYYY'))
```

;